# Glass bed for Ender 6

Tags: glass-bed, creality-ender-6

I have a warped glass bed on an Ender 6 that I recently bought. I want to replace this bed. However, the dimensions in which Ender 6 print bed comes (250x250x400 mm) are not available for purchase on sites like Amazon or Creality. Can anyone guide me about which bed I should buy?

Comment: You may be confusing the print size (the area you can print within) with the print bed (the physical size of the glass itself).

Comment: As @agarza has stated, you appear confused as to the size of the plate. The plate in the X-Y plane has only two dimensions, and then a thickness of only a few millimeters, in the Z direction. So, your quoted dimension of 250x250x400 makes little sense and would appear to be the build ***volume***, rather than the build ***area*** (i.e. the dimensions of the plate). Correct your search terms and you'll probably find the right size glass plate that you are looking for. Also, please [edit] and update your question with the correct size.

Comment: You say that you recently purchased the printer. DId the printer already come out of the box with a warped glass plate or did it become warped through being used, i.e. warped by the heat bed (assuming that it has a heat bed)? If the latter, then the glass provided probably wasn't heat-proof borosilicate glass - which *could* be grounds for complaint, if the printer was advertised as being supplied with borosilicate. Either way, something *seems* wrong with your purchase...

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to replace the glass, then you *could* go to any local glazing/window store and ask for a sheet of glass to be cut to the appropriate size.

It will probably be a *lot* cheaper than a glass sheet marketed as specific for 3D printers.

There are just one or two caveats:

- Whilst the type of glass is (probably) unimportant (*if you aren't using a heated bed*) ensure that the sheet of glass that you get your bed cut from is ***flat***. Ask the merchant for glass sheeting that is specifically made as flat as possible, and isn't already warped or with defects.
- If you have a heated bed then you will (most likely) require heat proof glass<sup>1</sup>, i.e. [borosilicate glass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borosilicate_glass), one example of which is Pyrex. This may be not as easy to source as "normal" glass for windows, but it's still worth asking at your local store.

---

Note that if the printer was recently purchased then it should still be under warranty and you could ask the supplier to send a new glass sheet.

---

#### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> You might (in all likelyhood) get away with just using normal glass plate, in junction with a heated bed, some glass is quite resiliant - it depends upon the quality and/or thickness (re. heat dissipation). Also, when taking into account the lower cost of normal glass, you might  not worry about any potential cracking and/or warping. However, if you prefer to err upon the side of caution, then use borosilicate glass.

Comment: Why special glass with a heated bed? Glass can take a lot more heat then any filament I know of

Comment: Good point, yet I thought that it would be prudent to err on the side of safe advice... I *could* replace `will (most likely)` with `might` and expand upon the answer...

Comment: The temperature of heated beds can increase quite quickly. Normal glass usually isn't made for big temperature differences between two of its ends (e.g. put one end in ice and the other above a fire) - therefor there are glasses specifically made to endure temperature differences (like laboratory glass). I doubt that on a heatbed, the temperature difference might be big enough to cause cracks, but in theory it is possible and might be a point to think about.